# Stripe not sending invoice emails to customers in test environment

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm integrating Stripe into one of the apps. When I send invoices through Node.js SDK it's not sending invoice emails to customers when I use the test environment API key. But when I use a live environment API key with the exact same code, it sends the invoice email to the customer.

Also when I send invoices from the Stripe dashboard in test mode, it is sending emails to customers. The issue seems to be only with SDK/API in the test mode.

Is it possible to send emails to customers even in test mode using Node.js SDK/API?

Answer (score 4):

Stripe doesn't send email in test mode.

From https://support.stripe.com/questions/not-receiving-email-sent-from-stripe:

> Stripe only sends email receipts for payments that are made with your live API key or through your live Dashboard. If you are expecting an email for a test transaction, one will not be sent.

Comment: hmm how am I supposed to properly test Invoice integration with credit cards requiring 3D secure then?

Comment: You may retrieve invoice URL from [`hosted_invoice_url`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-hosted_invoice_url) parameter in Invoice object from API response or webhook events (e.g. [`invoice.sent`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.sent) event). With the URL, you can perform 3DS on it.

Comment: Interesting, looking into it thanks 

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it is now possible to have Stripe send emails, even in Test mode. According to [this page](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/revenue-recovery/customer-emails?locale=en-US#test-your-configuration), emails will be sent if the email address is associated with a verified domain.

Comment: I can confirm that this is true. Not all emails are triggered in test mode, just the ones listed in the linked article.